# Error while trying to validate an iOS application before uploading it to the AppStore

Tags: xcode, ios6, app-store

When I try to validate an archive with an application using Organizer, before uploading it to the App Store, I get the following error:
"Unable to process lookupPurpleSoftwareVersions request at this time due to a general error".
Have anyone ever get this message? Is it due to an Apple developer portal problem?

Thank you,

Comment: It seems like it's just a bad day at the office isn't it? First TestFlight was down, now this, I broke my chair, what's next?! I'll set my pants on fire?!

Comment: @Cyupa, can you please post a photograph of that pant-thing when it happens?

Comment: @HermannKlecker It logged in and then it validated the app. Then I tried to upload it to the AppStore and it failed with a couple of error messages that weren't from my side for sure. I'm trying again right now.

Comment: I knew I should have submitted this update last night. Drat!

Comment: @Cyupa, I meant you setting your pants on fire. :)    However, uploading seems to work again now. ... "No issues were found in ..." Heureka!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an issue with the Apple servers. If I keep submitting, I sometimes see this error:

> "The server returned an invalid response. This may indicate that a
>   network proxy is interfering with communication, or that Apple servers
>   are having issues. Please try your request again later."

Answer (score 8):

Quit and relaunch Xcode. Archive the application again, now try to validate the app, it may work. (This scenario worked in my case :))

Comment: I dont need relaunch xcode, worked with validate option. Thanks!