# Unable to process app at this time due to a general error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

When I'm trying to upload my new app, I get the error

> Unable to process app at this time due to a general error

What is the problem?
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: I' encountering the same error. How long did it take?

Comment: My problem were resolved but it was not a server related issue - see my answer below

Comment: Do you check Provisioning Profiles exist for your app?

Comment: it's weird, in my case I just restarted xcode, delete old archive and create a new one and then it worked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is probably an Apple server issue, not an Xcode/iOS/OSX issue. Just wait patiently and Apple's servers will catch up to the traffic, or solve whatever issues they're having at their end.

If you're anxious, feel free to just sit there and restart Xcode until it works - but it's not restarting Xcode, only the time you waste that's solving the issue.

Comment: it may have been an apple issue (and time solved this), but uploading app worked for me after following Dee's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986099/error-while-trying-to-validate-an-ios-application-before-uploading-it-to-the-app): restart xcode, archive app, submit.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and waited for hours.

I figured out that my provisioning profile was not configured correctly.

My approach:

1. Delete distribution provisioning profile in dev center.
2. Create a new one (I used the wildcard app ID)
3. Update your profiles in Xcode settings
4. Choose the new profile when submitting the app

Comment: This helped. Removed all certificates and created new ones.

Comment: This is just a myth.