# Unable to validate Xcode archive - "General error"

Tags: xcode

When I go to validate my Xcode archive the following error appears `App Store Connect Operation Error. Unable to process app at this time due to a general error`. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324037/unable-to-process-app-at-this-time-due-to-a-general-error) question here but neither of the solutions have worked (changed the provisioning profile).

I'm fairly sure it's not a server issue as I have been experiencing the problem for over a month.

I am still able to distribute the app without validating it.